Is there anyway to stop highlighting for the auto-filled inputs?
This is stackoverflow login form.

When I try to fill the password with the one saved in the chrome password manager,

The background color turns into blue and this is same for every single websites including the one i am currently developing.
Is there any way to stop the background from transforming into blue using CSS?
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  background-color: transparent;
}

I tried adding this CSS to the input field, but it is not working.

Turn off the password manager?

I want to turn on the password manager without highlighting
